# iOS persistent cache directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My app downloads data from the internet and then stores it somewhere on the device, so when the user has no internet connection the data will still be available. I know about the cache folder, but according to Apple this directory will be removed if the device runs out of disk space. This is really a problem for my app, since this might break the app for users with low disk space and a bad internet connection.

My question: Where do I save those files without the risk of them being deleted by the system due to low disk space or whatever. I can't place it in the documents directory because Apple will reject my application.

I have tried storing it in the documents folder, and then using the following line of code to disable iCloud backups.

```
try? NSURL.fileURLWithPath(self.path).setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
```

But that doesn't work at all, it returns "()".

Answer (score 0):

From [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/setResourceValue:forKey:error:):

> HANDLING ERRORS IN SWIFT: In Swift, this method returns Void and is
>   marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in
>   cases of failure.

So `()` is the expected result.  The real test of "working" is whether the file contents are retrievable and whether they don't synch to the cloud.

As an aside, I like better your original idea to use the NSCaches directory.  It is *exactly* for content that can be regained with a fetch, but too expensive to fetch all the time.  And having it emptied to keep the device running well sounds like exactly the right behavior.

The requirement that you've given yourself to deliver rich content, have a low memory impact on the device and work well with little or no network is a commendably high bar... too high in my opinion, compared to anyone else.

It seems to me reasonable to detect a no cache, low memory, disconnected situation and just apologize to the user.  Tell them its their fault.